# Ionic Framework - Custom Google Now Commands

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing a home automation platform, whose mobile app will be built with Ionic Framework and Apache Cordova.

I would like my users to be able to use Google Now to speak commands such as "turn on the lights", which would launch my app, allowing me to handle said command.

I've seen the AutoVoice app, which allows users to add their own Google Voice commands using an accessibility service, so there must be a way. I just don't want my users to have to install another app to use mine.

Is this possible to do with Cordova and Ionic Framework?

Comment: have you looked at the speech recognition cordova plugin here? https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer

Comment: I have, and that's not want I want. I want to be able to add commands to Google Now.